# How to check if radio button is selected or not?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am try to check whether a radio button is checked or not using below jquery code but this is not working. So, How can I check if any radio button is selected or not ?

```
<script>
        function validationChecker(){

            let groupDetail = $('input[name=groupDetail]').val()
            if ((groupDetail === "") && (typeof groupDetail === "undefined")){
                console.log("Inside validations")
                console.log(groupDetail)
                return true;
            }
            console.log("Outside validations")
            console.log(groupDetail)
            return false;
        }
</script>

<input type="radio" id="<%= groups[index][0] %>" name="groupDetail" value="<%= groups[index] %>">
<label for="<%= groups[index][0] %>"><%= groups[index][1] %></label><br>
```

Comment: You can check it like: `$('input[name=groupDetail]').is(":checked")`

Comment: @MayankPandeyz Tysm Its worked